# Website down by Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, cpanel

We cannot access the Magento 1.9.0.1 Backend and our website is down with GoDaddy after they did a backup. None of our product links work and so does all the pages say something below:
[image]

We tried calling GoDaddy multiple times but nothing is resolved. We are losing lot of business. If you can give suggestions by posting below. That'll be great.

Comment: The error log number is your error log file located in var/report/1225649... Get content of the error and paste it here in your question, so that anyone can understand the actual problem occurring on your website

Answer (score 0):

- Connect to your server via **FTP** or **SSH**.
- Navigate to **{document-root-of-your-magento}/var/report** folder.
- Since there may be many report files, you can delete all the files and then reload the website in the browser.
- Now check the newly generated file to know more about the error.

Let me know if you need more help.